# Calling EnvelopesApi#update_document_tabs returns an error

Tags: docusignapi

I want to update all the tabs for a document at once. The document's envelope was created from a template which already has the recipients and tabs defined, and I am calling [this](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentTabs/update#tabs) endpoint with the following payload to update the tabs:

```
{
  "textTabs": [
    {
        "validationPattern": "",
        "validationMessage": "",
        "shared": "false",
        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
        "requireAll": "false",
        "value": "Some value",
        "originalValue": "Original value",
        "required": "false",
        "locked": "true",
        "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
        "disableAutoSize": "false",
        "maxLength": "4000",
        "tabLabel": "Address",
        "font": "lucidaconsole",
        "fontColor": "black",
        "fontSize": "size12",
        "localePolicy": {},
        "documentId": "1",
        "recipientId": "18870af6-8c21-4e4c-934c-ac329b6f7374",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "52",
        "yPosition": "94",
        "width": "132",
        "height": "18",
        "tabId": "032f2d80-7a93-4a7c-b969-aea2249fbd04",
        "templateRequired": "false",
        "tabType": "text"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the following error in response:

```
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_TAB_OPERATION",
  "message": "The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation. Updated tabs must all be Strikethrough or SmartSection tabs if you're not specifying a valid recipient."
}
```

`recipientId` is set to the value I received from [this](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentTabs/get) endpoint, but I've also tried setting it to "1" which is the `recipientId` I pass when creating the template.

What is the correct way to call this endpoint?

Comment: this recipientId in there, where did you get this GUID value from? the envelope or the template? same question for the tabId

Comment: That's covered under the error message. The `tabId` also came from the same endpoint.

Comment: can you explain again, do you use an envelope or a template?

Comment: I get the error message when creating an envelope from a template. I initially create a new envelope with a template id, then retrieve a list of the tabs on that envelope, then try to update them.

Comment: yes, I understand. What I'm asking is this: the recipientId you have in the code above - is that the template's or the envelope's?

Comment: Ah, ok. The recipient id came from the endpoint that returns envelope tabs, so I'm assuming it's from the envelope.

Comment: please share all your code, how you create the envelope, how you get the envelope tabs etc.

Comment: Here is the minimum code I could reproduce it with: [github](https://github.com/yulianovdey/docusign-update-tabs).

Comment: well, if that's all your code, I know exactly what is your issue. You don't have a recipient with recipientId "18870af6-8c21-4e4c-934c-ac329b6f7374"

Comment: To clarify, the payload in my original response is not related to the code. That code generates the same error I posted above when you give it a template with a text tab. I guess another way to ask my question is how would I change that code so that it doesn't throw an error and updates the tabs?

Comment: you would have to dynamically find our what is the recipientID, it's different every time and inject it into the request to update the tab

Comment: Do you happen to know if this behavior is documented somewhere? As far as I understand I _am_ dynamically finding out the `recipientId` because it's coming back with the tab. I also tried listing out the recipients, and injecting the `recipientIdGuid` as the `recipientId`, as well as using `1` for the value, and mixing and matching `recipientIdGuid` and `recipientId`. They all return the same error.

Comment: Something else that is interesting is if I take the `recipientId` in the tab and pass it to [this](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/update) endpoint, updating tabs works fine. Doesn't that mean the recipient id is valid?

Comment: what is the status of the envelope when you make the call? is it still in draft mode?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the status is still `created`.

Comment: can you tell me the envelopeId?

Comment: `2ed63c86-6767-4915-892d-fc339bbaebbb`. Thank you for looking into it!

Comment: that envelopeID does not match the recipientId and tabID you have below. Can you get me all three IDs that you used together and give you the error?

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this with the code I provided? Here is a set of IDs that matches:

envelope id - 4c89912b-b98f-478d-ac48-78e437f54abb
tab id - b9839188-1d7f-44f5-a9e0-e2cacf89f850
recipient id - 684512d5-8ce9-4b34-b70a-97e93d7ddfa7

Comment: thanks, I have someone looking into this, it may be a bug. However, they noticed that after the failed call, you made another call that did succeed. That was a call to update envelope tabs. Can this be a workaround?

Comment: Yes, the example code then uses the same recipient id and [this endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/update) to successfully update the tabs, but if there is more than one recipient we would have to make that call for each one which would be slower and worse for our API quota.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yulian, It appears there's a bug in the UpdateDocumentTabs endpoint that is causing this issue and we're looking into it and hope to have an update soon.

As a workaround, you can use the UpdateRecipientTabs endpoint for now. I realize this would mean making additional API calls for the same purpose. If you need your API hourly quota increased - you can contact me and I can help with that.

Comment: At this point there's no update, I'm sorry, is there any reason you cannot use the workaround?

Comment: It has been almost a year, and the issue still remains... The only way I've found to update the tabs value was using EnvelopeRecipientTabs update endpoint, but this way I have to update the tabs per recipient.

Comment: Seems to still be a problem - October 2021

Comment: You mean that UpdateDocumentTabs doesn't work, but you can still use UpdateRecipientTabs, right? this is still the case, yes.

Comment: This is still an issue @InbarGazit whats up with that ? Jul-2022